# Regular expression to remove text + int

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression to remove the following from a string `page=55&` or `page=77&`

The string can be for example:

```
var=104&anothervar=10&page=14&name=stack
```

And the result should be:

```
var=104&anothervar=10&name=stack
```

What's the appropriate expression to use for preg_replace?

Comment: Try it preg_replace('/page=[0-9]+\&/', '', $str)

Comment: great, that seems to work

Comment: Why do you say that this works and @hjpotter's solution (or mine) doesn't?

Comment: because it does, and yours doesn't :p

Comment: It's exactly the same expression, though, except for the starting word boundary.

Comment: It seems to work also for the last case, for some reason

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) function.

**Example:**

```
$str = 'var=104&anothervar=10&page=14&name=stack';
$str = preg_replace('/&?page=\d+&?/', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

`&page=\d+?`

- `[&]?` means 0 or 1 occurence of `&` character. (in case it was first parametr ampersand with no ampresand in the begining)
- `\d+?` means at least 1 or more number after `=`

**Output:**

```
var=104&anothervar=104&name=stack
```

Comment: This is not locale-aware

Comment: What I mean is that if you're in a different country that does not use the western numbers, your regex will fail. You should use \d as others have suggested

Comment: It gives the output as OP wanted so I don't think it affects his locale. But I'll change it. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: that expression doesn't really work... It doesn't remove the last '&' and it doesn't consider numbers of more than 1 digit.

Comment: @luqita and Tim Pietzcker http://codepad.viper-7.com/KipWzN working example with the code above. It works for number with more than 1 digits + is responsible for that. I agree it won't remove last & I'll edit it.

Comment: @Robert: It changed the number `10` into `104`, though, because the reluctant `+?` only matched the first digit!

Comment: Yes you're right. Thank you for paying attention. I've edited it.

Comment: Thank you for justifying why using a built-in as opposed to a custom-crafted solution is better

Comment: Well, now it changes `var=104&anothervar=10&page=14&name=stack` into `var=104&anothervar=10name=stack`. See why regex might be the wrong tool for this? @hd1 had it right from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) and then recombine them eliminating the parameter you don't want. No need for regular expressions (again).

Comment: I've thought of this solution but in this case it's more code to write and `preg_replace()` simply solves problem.

Comment: @Robert: Maybe more code, but if it conveys the intention clearer, and if it is "battle-hardened" against cases a regex fails to cover (which I would expect `parse_str` to be), then this is the right way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bpage=\d+&/', '', $subject);
```

The [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` is necessary unless you want to change `"var=123&subpage=456&name=stack"` into `"var=123&subname=stack"`.

Comment: I know the OP provided a concrete string but if the parameter is the last one? Or the first one?

Comment: @enenen: It should work if it's the first one, but you're right - if it's the last one (or the only one), then this won't work.

Comment: This doesn't work when page=x is the last parameter

Comment: @luqita: Well, you wrote in your question that you want to "remove the following from a string `page=55&` or `page=77&`"...

Comment: correct, and your expression doesn't remove it for all cases

Comment: @luqita: It does for all cases that end in a `&`, which is what you asked for.

Comment: @luqita I agree with Tim you wanted solution that removes from string you gave the page there are solutions that does it. You didn't specify in question that page= can be anywere in param string. If you want it then use `parse_str()` as hd1 suggested. The answer covers your question. +1 For Tim